Strange calculus involved in work and power
If force is given by $$F(t)= 3t^2i + t^3j$$ and velocity is $$v(t)= 5t^2i + 2tj$$ then what is work done in time $t$. Now we can obtain power by their dot product $F.v$ and then integrate power to get net work done. Second approach could be to integrate velocity to get displacement and then take dot product of force and displacement $F.x$ to find work done.
But i am getting different results in both cases. Here is my approach:

Now I am confused over which approach is right and why. I don't know where I am missing.

This is an extremely poor question. You cannot move a term outside an integral if it is not a constant.

@VincentThacker I haven't moved any term outside. I just obtained displacement separately and then took dot product with force.

The correct formula for work is
$$
\Delta W = \int P d t = \int \vec{F} \cdot \vec{v} \,dt
$$
Now, if $\vec{F}$ is constant, then we can take it out of the integral and write
$$
\Delta W = \vec{F} \cdot \int \vec{v}\, dt = \vec{F} \cdot \Delta \vec{x}.
$$
It should now be clear to you why you are getting different results with your two formulas, and which formula is correct.
